# trouble getting the code to barplot or column plot these dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

data.frame(BADAGRY_CREEK_PUBLICATION_2)

```
       month station COPEPODA CYCLOPOIDA
1       MAY.       1       25          0
2       JUNE       1       10          5
3       JULY       1        4          0
4     AUGUST       1        5          5
5  SEPTEMBER       1       20          5
6       MAY.       2       20          0
7       JUNE       2       10         10
8       JULY       2        3          5
9     AUGUST       2       20          0
10 SEPTEMBER       2       40          0
11      MAY.       3       35          5
12      JULY       3        5          0
13      JUNE       3       25          5
14    AUGUST       3       35          5
15 SEPTEMBER       3       10          5
   JUVENILE.STAGES Number.of.Species..S.
1               15                     5
2               35                     6
3                0                     1
4               10                     4
5               15                     5
6               15                     5
7                5                     4
8                0                     2
9               10                     4
10              25                     6
11              20                     6
12               5                     2
13              30                     6
14               0                     3
15              30                     6
   Number.of.Individuals..N.
1                         40
2                         50
3                          4
4                         20
5                         40
6                         35
7                         25
8                          8
9                         30
10                        75
11                        60
12                        10
13                        60
14                        40
15                        50
```

was hoping tp plot stations on the x axis, with the count of each variable reflecting on the bars along the y axis. i tried this code

`ggplot(BADAGRY_CREEK_PUBLICATION_2, aes(x=station)) + geom_bar()` [this was the bar plotted which doesnot reflect the data gathered]

the result was not well plotted

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(BADAGRY_CREEK_PUBLICATION_2)` copy and paste from your console to your question?

Comment: What does "not well plotted" mean? What were you expecting, what did you get, and how did those two things differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what you are looking for here, since you also have `month` in your data. If you want to ignore `month` in your plot, you could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

BADAGRY_CREEK_PUBLICATION_2 %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(1:2)) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value), station = station) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(station), y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme_light() +
  labs(x = "Station", y = "Count")
```

[image]

To include month, you probably need facets:

```r
BADAGRY_CREEK_PUBLICATION_2 %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(1:2)) %>%
  mutate(month = factor(sub("\\.", "", month), levels = c("MAY", "JUNE",
         "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(station), y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  facet_grid(month~.) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme_light() +
  labs(x = "Station", y = "Count")
```

[image]

---

**Question data in reproducible format**

```r
BADAGRY_CREEK_PUBLICATION_2 <- structure(list(month = c("MAY.", "JUNE", 
"JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", 
"MAY.", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "MAY.", "JULY", 
"JUNE", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER"), station = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), COPEPODA = c(25L, 10L, 
4L, 5L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 3L, 20L, 40L, 35L, 5L, 25L, 35L, 10L), 
    CYCLOPOIDA = c(0L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 10L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 
    0L, 5L, 5L, 5L), JUVENILE.STAGES = c(15L, 35L, 0L, 10L, 15L, 
    15L, 5L, 0L, 10L, 25L, 20L, 5L, 30L, 0L, 30L), Number.of.Species..S. = c(5L, 
    6L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L), 
    Number.of.Individuals..N. = c(40L, 50L, 4L, 20L, 40L, 35L, 
    25L, 8L, 30L, 75L, 60L, 10L, 60L, 40L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"))
```

Comment: thanks alot! @Allan Cameron. got it. however, i like to change variable "name" to "species"

Comment: @KayAwo you can add the argument 'name =  "Species"` inside `scale_fill_brewer`

Comment: suppose i want to have the columns appear as a pattern fill so as to easily distinguish each variable list. not sure where to twitch. thanks

Comment: @KayAwo you would need to do `library(ggpattern)` and use `fill_pattern = name` instead of `fill = name`